# Alasql result to be used in other parts of the program

Tags: javascript, arrays, alasql

I have imported an XLSX file but i cannot seem to use the result outside its function:

```
var dataResult;


alasql('select * from xlsx("adat.xlsx",{headers:true, sheetid:"adat", range:"A1:B21"})',
         [],function(data) {
               dataResult= data;
         });

 console.log(dataResult);
```

The result of the console.log is "undefined"

Could someone help me solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think you should try to use ` this.dataResult `  inside the function

Comment: That solution doesn't work, but thnk you trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a promise instead. The console.log is called before the result has been obtained.

```
var dataResult;
var checkResults = function () {
    console.log(dataResult);
}
alasql
.promise('select * from xlsx("adat.xlsx",{headers:true, sheetid:"adat", range:"A1:B21"}))
    .then(function (res) {
        dataResult = res;
        checkResults();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error:', err);
    });
```